# How to keep track of variable property in different view controller

Tags: ios, swift, var

I have 3 view controller: in the 1st VC I am fetch data by a service call. The fetched data is in an array of objects. When a button in the 1st VC is tapped, I pass that array of objects to the 2nd VC where it will show the array of objects in a table view. In the table view cell there is a like button, which shows the total likes from the object. When I tap on the table view cell it opens the 3rd VC, where it shows details and also the like button.

I pass the object like this:

```
func openImagesList() {
    if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImagesList") as? ImagesListVC {            
        vc.imageModel = self.imagesModel
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Now the object is changing in the 3rd and 2nd VCs, but when it gets changed I want the same changes in the 1st VC too. How can I keep track of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more modern alternative to using a delegate is to use a closure. For example, let's say you want to pass data from `SecondVC` back to `FirstVC`:

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController {

    private func presentSecondVC() {
        let secondVC = SecondVC()
        secondVC.dataChangedHandler = dataChanged(data:)
        present(secondVC, animated: true)
    }

    private func dataChanged(data: SomeModel) {
        // do stuff with data
    }

}
```

In `SecondVC`, you need a variable for the handler:

```
class SecondVC: UIViewController {

    var dataChangedHandler: ((SomeModel) -> Void)?

    private var data: SomeModel = ...

    private func dataDidChange() {
        dataChangedHandler?(data)
    }

}
```

Instead of a delegate, you're using `dataChangedHandler`,  a closure to pass data back and forth. You can easily extend this method to three view controllers by passing around the reference to `dataChanged(data:)`.

Using closures is concise (you don't even need a protocol) and versatile. It is also very modular, as you don't have to directly expose `FirstVC`.